# Cannot delete registry key - Error while deleting key

Tags: windows-registry

I have looked through the other article and haven't found anything. It is a Google Chrome key. I have been trying to delete it. Things I have tried:

1. Taking ownership (errors that it can't apply changed)
2. Running regedit via psexec as system (no change. still can't delete)
3. Running regedit offline after booting Windows 10 DVD (loaded system hive but couldn't find entry at that point)

What else can I try to get rid of this bad boy?

[image]

Comment: Have you been running RegEdit _explicitly_ as "Run as administrator"? Keys in HKLM often require this.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. Same error.

Comment: What are the permissions on that key?

Comment: You should load SOFTWARE hive file instead of SYSTEM, and I think you'd better run either reg delete in cmd or remove-item in PowerShell using NSudo to run them as TrustedInstaller instead of using regedit.exe, it might yield a better result.

Comment: You might try running Regedit as *TrustedInstaller*. See https://blog.nirsoft.net/2020/02/25/run-program-as-trustedinstaller/

Comment: Can you add/link the output of:
`get-acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.microsoft.browsercore | fl`
and `whoami /all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had luck deleting locked keys by both taking ownership of the key and ensuring full permission for "everyone" then deleting.  For some reason, giving the current user ownership AND full permission does not always work.

1. Run regedit as administrator
2. Set owner to any admin user (perhaps the active one)
3. Set permission for "everyone" to full
4. Delete key

If still not working, using WinPE or other alternate boot method edit registry and load SOFTWARE as suggested previously.